# how to restrict only one screen in portrait mode and others in landscape in ipad

Tags: ipad, ios7

My app run only in landscape mode, but i want one View in portrait mode for UIImagePicker.

I write following in viewController

```
 (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    } else {
        return (interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }

}

// iOS6
 (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

// iOS6
 (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        return  (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
//              return (UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionLeftToRight || UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft);

    } else {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    }

}

// Added after comment
 (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }

}
```

And on DriverAddPage.m I had write

```
 (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

// iOS6
 (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        return  (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);


    } else {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    }

}
```

What I do wrong? Help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i did this in my application. By custom navigation controller.

Comment: Send me your email address. i will send you the code which solve all your orientation issue.